# nginx ssl server https setRequestHeader

Tags: javascript, nginx, ssl-certificate, gunicorn

I have a nginx server. When I use normally port 80, everything goes well.
But now I use port 443 for ssl server. Now I cannot use the following code with javascript. How can I handle to use this code with ssl server?

Is working with http but not with https.
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', ' Token ' + JWT);

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the nginx listener for port 443?

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ...
}
```